# Is any molecule's ground state a singlet?

Tags: quantum-spin, many-body

I am reading the Hartree-Fock method.

For a molecule with an even number of electrons, the ground state HF determinant is a singlet for sure. It is said the ground state of the molecule is a singlet in the experiment.

I was wondering if the molecule with an odd number of electrons, is the ground state of the molecule still a singlet generally in the experiment?

Comment: I'm far from an expert on Hartree-Fock, but doesn't a singlet state by definition mean "net spin of zero"?  You can't couple together an odd number of spin-1/2 fermions to get a state with a net spin of zero.